# Little twist to macro - Shift multiple columns down

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck again..

I have used a macro for a long time, but now I need to add a feature to the macro.

Sub InsRow()

```
Dim c 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

For Each c In Selection 

    If c.Offset(0, -1) <> c And c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then 
        c.Offset(0, 1).Insert shift:=xlDown 
        c.Insert Shift:=xlDown 

    End If 


Next c 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

This macro looks if the value in column B is the same as in column A. When this is not the case, it shifts the cells of column B and C down, till they sync again. However, I want column d till.... also to shift down. How can I add this feature to the macro?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub InsRow() 
Dim c 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

For Each c In Selection 
    If c.Offset(0, -1) <> c And c.Offset(0, -1) <> "" Then 
        'Change the "D" to whichever column you want to shift down.
        Range(cells(c.Row,"B"),cells(c.Row,"D")).Insert shift:=xlDown 
        c.Insert Shift:=xlDown 
    End If 
Next c 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```

The above sub will shift down for all columns from B to whichever column you specify. Currently it will shift columns B, C, and D down.

Comment: Thanks a lot! First it wasn't working for me, but then I saw that you used B instead of C. It is really nice that I can set the range of the columns (the starting column AND the ending column). Thanks for your time and have a nice day! :)